# How to change color of browse button?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I am using custom file input of bootstrap:

[image]

How can I change color of the "Browse" button?

What all I tried:

1. Added color tag to custom-file-input
2. Added color tag to custom-file-label
   Both did not work. On inspect, when I try to get the responsible css class it shows custom-file-input. However, the changes don't work.

Comment: Can you share some codes?

Answer (score 0):

## tag is not button

can you try bg-[color]?

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Default</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
</div>
```

if example code like this. you can input bg-primary here

```
<span class="input-group-text bg-primary" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Default</span>
```

## tag is button

you can use btn-[color] instead.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons/

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
```